# Python List Error

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I was writing a simple genetic program to test out the process, but got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "evolution.py", line 43, in <module>
    nextgen += test[operator.indexOf(list(fits), m+chance)]
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

on the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random
import operator

mutationchance = 0.01
simtime        = 1000

# quadratic optimizer
class Organism:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
        self.epsilon = 0.01
    def fitness(self):
        return self.a*(self.x**2) + self.b*(self.x) + self.c
    def mutate(self):
        self.x += random.random() - 0.5
    def describe(self):
        return self.x

def condmutate(org, chance):
    if random.random() <= chance:
        org.mutate()
    return org

test = [Organism(i) for i in range(-10, 10)]    

generation = 0

while generation < simtime:
    fits = [test[i].fitness() for i in range(0, len(test) - 1)]
    sumf = sum(fits)
    i = 0
    nextgen = list()
    while i < len(fits) / 2:
        chance = random.random() * sumf
        j = 0
        shg = [fits[i] - chance for i in range(0, len(test) - 1)]
        m = min(shg)
        nextgen += test[operator.indexOf(list(fits), m+chance)]
        nextgen += test[operator.indexOf(list(fits), m+chance)]
    test = [condmutate(test[i], mutationchance) for i in range(0, len(nextgen) - 1)]
    generation += 1

print "result: ", max([test[i].describe() for i in range(0, len(test) - 1)])
```

I am new to Python, so it may just be a newbie mistake.

Comment: What some of us do is put `print` statements (or `print()` functions, depending on your version) in front of the failing statement to print out the various variables to be sure of the types.  You could try that -- add `print` statements to show what the values of `fits`, `test`, `m` and `chance` are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add an element into `nextgen`, use `nextgen.append(...)` instead. `+=` is the wrong operator.

Specifically, `+=` on a list concatenates it with another *iterable*, not element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what's going on here, but to add items to a list you should use "append".  You can also probably simplifiy your code a bit to make it more readable and maintainable.

Try changing:

```
nextgen += test[operator.indexOf(list(fits), m+chance)]
```

to:

```
nextgen.append(test[fits.indexOf(m+chance)])
```

But maybe I'm missing something and you have a good reason to use the "operator" module and re-wrap your list in a list?

Answer (score 0):

You have several list comprehensions in your code of the form:

```
[test[i].fitness() for i in range(0, len(test) - 1)]
```

Please don't do this. It's a serious abuse of how iteration is supposed to work in Python.

Creating an index and then using it to index a list is horribly indirect. Imagine if you asked me to crack a dozen eggs, and I responded by writing the numbers 0 through 11 on a piece of paper, and then looking at each number in turn, counting along the egg carton to the corresponding slot, pulling out the egg and cracking it. The paper is a useless distraction. Just crack the eggs.

Further, `range` **does not include** the endpoint. `range(0, 4)` produces the list [0, 1, 2, 3]. Thus, your iteration skips the last element of the list. I can't tell whether this is deliberate or not.

If you want to iterate over every element:

```
[item.fitness() for item in test]
```

If you want to iterate over every element except the last:

```
[item.fitness() for item in test[:-1]]
```

I also can't tell what you're doing with the `while i < len(fits) / 2:` loop. How exactly are you expecting `i` to change? You haven't written anything that changes `i`, *except the list comprehensions*. If you weren't aware that list comprehensions "leak" their iteration variable into the local variable dictionary, then you're in for a nasty surprise. (If you need to prevent such a leak, you can use a generator comprehension; if you need a list, you can create a list from the generator comprehension, e.g. `list(x for x in whatever)`.) If you were aware, and are depending on that behaviour, you're writing needlessly tricky code. Don't be clever. Explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you should use `nextgen.append(...)` rather than `+=` and much of the code could be cleaned up for clarity and simplicity. In addition, it appears that the variable `chance` is not really used, since you first subtract it and then add it back again. As a result, you will always append the minimum fitness element and there is no randomness in your code.